# How to cash out a currency?

Tags: payments

I am implementing an anchor which will send transactions on behalf of users but I am very confused with one question,

How to cash out the assets in the account which is paid to me from another anchor in the network.

Does stellar dex give provision to cash out ?

Please help giving an elaborative answer .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by cashing out?

Comment: If some one sends assets to an account how is it supposed to be convert to government currency ?

Comment: If you have got asset from another account that means you have created `trustline` with that anchor which means this anchor has agreed to trade you back other assets. Another way is to trade this assets in `dex` and exchange for another assets like `eth` which you can cash out by sending to some exchanges.